# How to read NA value?

Tags: r, csv

file t.csv:

```
a ; b ; c ; d
1 ; 2 ; NA; 4
5 ; NA; 6 ; 7
```

I read the file t.csv

```
> t <-  read.table("t.csv",header = T, sep = ";")
```

What I expect:

```
> str(t)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ a: num  1 5
 $ b: num  2 NA
 $ c: num  NA 6
 $ d: num  4 7
```

What I get

```
> str(t)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ a: num  1 5
 $ b: Factor w/ 2 levels " 2 "," NA": 1 2
 $ c: Factor w/ 2 levels " 6 "," NA": 2 1
 $ d: num  4 7
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `strip.white=TRUE` in the `read.table`

```
dat <- read.table('t.csv', header=TRUE, sep=';', strip.white=TRUE)
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  4 variables:
#$ a: int  1 5
#$ b: int  2 NA
#$ c: int  NA 6
#$ d: int  4 7
```

To get `numeric` class, it can be specified with `colClasses`

```
dat <- read.table('t.csv', header=TRUE, sep=';', 
       strip.white=TRUE, colClasses=rep('numeric',4))
str(dat)
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  4 variables:
#$ a: num  1 5
#$ b: num  2 NA
#$ c: num  NA 6
#$ d: num  4 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
read.csv("t.csv", sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings = " NA")
```